# Problem: users are logged out automatically without any reason, while navigating to the website

Tags: 7, users

Hi After some time Im having a very serius problem, while logged in users interact with the website they are logged out without any reason.

For example, I log in, then I interact some minutes with the website, then for example I try to access to create an article (or whatever) then I get an access denied because I was logged out automatically, I do not know why...

Any idea?

Comment: Is your site behind a load balancer, reverse proxy, or something similar?  Are you using alternate cache storage (like memcache)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some settings regarding cookie session lifetime in the settings.php file. These settings might not be allowed for overwriting and your server might have its own rules.

```
 ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 200000);
```

Check admin/reports/status/php.